# How to apply shared css file between multiple components in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I developed a `ReactJs` app that contain multiple components which every one of them have a seperate css file.

But now i need to clean up and have a shared css file that contains the commun styles for all of the components.

I want to have it done the best way.

I would love to have some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Sass and then working with [mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)?

Comment: I am working on a client project, I don't want to use sass, just plain css

Comment: then you could create global classes that you could use across all the time, create globals.scss and import into main file and then you will need to add those classes to className in jsx. Dont really see any other solution in css.

Answer (score -1):

For this, also use a import statement in css files, or you can import all css files into index.jsx file